# How to write a state machine to solve the Count the smiley faces?

Tags: javascript, state-machine

I have solved the problem [Count the smiley faces](https://www.codewars.com/kata/583203e6eb35d7980400002a):

> Given an array (arr) as an argument complete the function countSmileys that should return the total number of smiling faces.
>
> Rules for a smiling face:
>
> - Each smiley face must contain a valid pair of eyes. Eyes can be marked as `:` or `;`
> - A smiley face can have a nose but it does not have to. Valid characters for a nose are `-` or `~`
> - Every smiling face must have a smiling mouth that should be marked with either `)` or `D`
>
> No additional characters are allowed except for those mentioned.
>
> **Valid smiley face examples:** `:) :D ;-D :~)`
> **Invalid smiley faces:** `;( :> :} :]`
>
> **Example**
>
> ```
> countSmileys([':)', ';(', ';}', ':-D']);       // should return 2;
> countSmileys([';D', ':-(', ':-)', ';~)']);     // should return 3;
> countSmileys([';]', ':[', ';*', ':$', ';-D']); // should return 1;
> ```
>
> **Note**
>
> In case of an empty array return 0. You will not be tested with invalid input (input will always be an array). Order of the face (eyes, nose, mouth) elements will always be the same.

Then when I look through the solutions I find that many people use regexp. Then I want write a state machine to implement regexp and solve this problem. But I failed. This is my code:

```js
function countSmileys(smileys) {
  let state = smileyHasValidEye;
  return smileys.filter(smiley => {
    for (let s of [...smiley]) {
      state = state(s);
    }
    return state === true;
  }).length;
}

function smileyHasValidEye(s) {
  if (s === ':' || s === ';') {
    return smileyHasValidNose;
  }
  return smileyHasValidEye;
}

function smileyHasValidNose(s) {
  if (s === '-' || s === '~') {
    return smileyHasValidMouth;
  }
  return smileyHasValidMouth(s);
}

function smileyHasValidMouth(s) {
  if (s === ')' || s === 'D') {
    return true;
  }
  return;
}

console.log(countSmileys([':)', ';(', ';}', ':-D']));
```

And the error I get is:

```
state = state(s);
              ^

TypeError: state is not a function
```

Then I debugged my code I found the procedure doesn't enter the `smileyHasValidNose` function. Then I don't know the reason.

Comment: not really sure but I just observed that most functions return a function, while smileyHasValidNose does `return smileyHasValidMouth(s)` invocation, returning a value rather than a function.

Comment: What is that problem you mention? I'm unfamiliar with it and thus I'm unfamiliar with what your code is trying to do. I wouldn't be able to know how to fix it or how to use any potential answers here.

Comment: @VLAZ  [Conunt the smiley faces](https://www.codewars.com/kata/583203e6eb35d7980400002a) is a problem in codewars, and I want to solve it by state-machine.

Comment: This is information that belongs *in the question*. And not just the link - if the content of the link changes or the link is dead for any reason, then the question loses its meaning. I have edited the question to include the context for it. Please in the future add all relevant information in the question from the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you don't really reset `state` in between smileys. So the next smiley state will be `true` which you can't call (it's not a function).

You could use a local variable for `state` that resets it to the first function (the first step).

```js
function countSmileys(smileys) {
  let firstStep = smileyHasValidEye;
  return smileys.filter(smiley => {
    let state = firstStep;
    for (let s of [...smiley]) {
      state = state(s);
    }
    return state === true;
  }).length;
}

function smileyHasValidEye(s) {
  if (s === ':' || s === ';') {
    return smileyHasValidNose;
  }
  return smileyHasValidEye;
}

function smileyHasValidNose(s) {
  if (s === '-' || s === '~') {
    return smileyHasValidMouth;
  }
  return smileyHasValidMouth(s);
}

function smileyHasValidMouth(s) {
  if (s === ')' || s === 'D') {
    return true;
  }
  return;
}

console.log(countSmileys([':)', ';(', ';}', ':-D']));
```

This code however, will error if there's more on the string besides the smiley (or a partial of the smiley).

I would change `smileyHasValidMouth` to return `false` if it doesn't detect a smiley. Just to be more consistent here...

```
function smileyHasValidMouth(s) {
  if (s === ')' || s === 'D') {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

And adjust your loop to exit early if it finds a value that is not a function.

```
    for (let s of [...smiley]) {
      state = state(s);
      if(typeof state !== 'function') return state;
    }
```

```js
function countSmileys(smileys) {
  let firstStep = smileyHasValidEye;
  return smileys.filter(smiley => {
    let state = firstStep;
    for (let s of [...smiley]) {
      state = state(s);
      if (typeof state !== 'function') return state;
    }
  }).length;
}

function smileyHasValidEye(s) {
  if (s === ':' || s === ';') {
    return smileyHasValidNose;
  }
  return smileyHasValidEye;
}

function smileyHasValidNose(s) {
  if (s === '-' || s === '~') {
    return smileyHasValidMouth;
  }
  return smileyHasValidMouth(s);
}

function smileyHasValidMouth(s) {
  if (s === ')' || s === 'D') {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(countSmileys([':~(', ':>', ':D', ':(', ':o>', ';)', ':)']));
```

Comment: Thank you so much, you solved my this problem. But another problem is when my procedure test the array *[':~(', ':>', ':D', ':(', ':o>', ';)', ':)']* it still report *Uncaught TypeError: state is not a function* in the console. I debugged and I find it's because the stirng ":o>", the second and third character are both not matched. But I haven't figured out a solution for a long time. Is there a approach to solve it?

Comment: @Ha0ran yes, I was going to write a second suggestion initially to address that problem but I didn't know if it would apply to your case.

Comment: @Ha0ran see updated post

Comment: That's it.Thanks again!